# Same package with differents version on the same solution. Strange behaviour

Tags: c#, nuget-package

I have a package problem in my solution on visual studio.

I have 2 project, first one is a web project (.NET Framework 4.6.1) and the second is library project (.NET Framework 4.6.1).

Utils is my nuget package (.NET STANDARD 2.0) and Mailing is another nuget package.
Mailing depends on Utils.

Utils and Mailing are installed on web project and library project.

On Web project, Utils has the version 2.1.0.
On Library project, he has the version 2.2.5

When I launch my solution, the project web use the project library.
The web project use Utils 2.1.0 and not the version 2.2.5.
I wanted to know why web project uses the oldest version.

Comment: Have you checked the web config to see what version is specified?

Answer (score 0):

The first place I would check is the solution level NuGet Package Management window. To do this: Right click Solution -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution.

Then you will be able to see if your two projects are using different versions. If that does not fix your problem, I would check to see if your Web project has a direct project reference to the other library by right clicking on `Dependencies` under your project, then clicking `Add References`.

Comment: My web project has a reference to library. But when i want to use a method of library with web, a web method is called and not the library method.